# Lambda@edge takes more than 30 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda-edge

I have a lambda functions in one AZ in EU and another one in `us-east-1` to be used via `CloudFront` triggers.

```
  CloudFront --> @edge function -> lambda function
```

Sometimes, it takes a while for the second lambda invoke to be finished which hits the lambda@edge limits. It would be fine if it happens in async but I don't see any results when I run it async. Here is the code:

```js
"use strict";

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "eu-west-1",
});
const querystring = require("querystring");


exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

  let request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  let params = querystring.parse(request.querystring);
  if (params.key) {
    
    const payload = {
      /* my payload */
    };
    const lambda_params = {
      FunctionName: "lambda-func-name",
      Payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
    };

    const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

    const resp= await lambda.invoke(lambda_params);
    console.log("Finished");
  } else {
    // allow the response to pass through
     return {
        "status":404,
        "body":"an error"
      }
  }
};
```

the second lambda func would process some images and putting the results in the S3, but when I call it async, I don't see any results. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you invoking the 2nd lambda async? Did you use `InvocationType: 'Event'`? Anyway, with Lambda@Edge, you shouldn't be waiting for any task. Lambda@Edge is supposed to be very lightweight, very quick process. You should add an SQS and invoke the 2nd lambda that way instead.

Comment: the task is like the image resizing which, but for big images, it takes more than 30 seconds. And I used `InvocationType` : 'Event' , no success yet

Comment: Make sure you have the `lambda:InvokeAsync` permission attached to the 1st lambda. And check if the 2nd lambda is actually being invoked when you're calling it async. console.log() something and check the logs in cloudwatch.

Comment: How exactly did you use `InvocationType`? Judging by the code that you posted, you are missing an `InvocationType` parameter among your Lambda params.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a lengthy runtime seems like a very bad use case for Lambda@Edge. Maybe you should redesign your system to handle that.

Please note that Lambda@Edge has [a **function timeout limit of maximum 30 seconds** in case of origin events and only 5 seconds for viewer events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html). Moreover, there is [a compute utilization limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html):

> CloudFront Functions have a limit on the time they can take to run,
> measured as compute utilization. Compute utilization is a number
> between 0 and 100 that indicates the amount of time that the function took to run as a percentage of the maximum allowed time. For example, a compute utilization of 35 means that the function completed in 35% of the maximum allowed time.

With respect to your current design, in order to invoke Lambda asynchronously the `invoke` function should specify the correct invocation type argument. So instead

```js
const lambda_params = {
  FunctionName: "lambda-func-name",
  Payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
};
```

you should use

```js
const lambda_params = {
  FunctionName: "lambda-func-name",
  InvocationType: "Event", // <= you are missing this parameter
  Payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
};
```

By default, the `InvocationType` value is set to `RequestResponse`. This means synchronous invocation. See [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) for reference.